# Change save to file name but from the client

Tags: javascript, html, http, client-side, firefox-addon

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168173/change-name-of-file-sent-to-client) asks about file name the servers sends and the fix was quite simply a content-disposition header in the http response.

What I interested in is does anyone know of any way to do this from the client side if the file name is already known? Is there any special javascript to do this for example?

A site I have to use but not mine has a FileDownload.aspx but it doesn't send the content-disposition header. I know the filename and would like to be able to create a firefox extensions to use for the poorly coded web site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Save Link in Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/613) plugin. It allows to specify a pattern for the filename (no matter what the website suggests). There is [another version which saves images](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/614). If the plugin doesn't solve your problem, it can serve as a template.