# How do I change a filename on-download with javascript?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

The script adds a download link for videos (on a specific site). How do I change the filename to something else while downloading?

```
Example URL:
"http://website.com/video.mp4"

Example of what I want the filename to be saved as during download:
"The_title_renamed_with_javascript.mp4"
```

Comment: Because changing a file name isn't possible in JavaSCript, this question is an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168173/change-name-of-file-sent-to-client

Comment: @Rob W, this question is not at all a duplicate of [Q 168173](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168173/change-name-of-file-sent-to-client).   That is about a web application, this Q is about a client-side script.  The OP has no control over the target page or server.

Comment: @Brock Adams What the OP asks is not possible at the client's side. Therefore, the question moves to "How to change the file name of the specific file", which has already been asked multiple times by other users.

Comment: @Rob W, that doesn't make any sense.  Anyway, this **is** possible client side, just not by using only Greasemonkey JS.

Comment: Im pretty sure it's possible.

This script does it, I just cant figure out how:
[http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/62634](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/62634)

Comment: @supercoolville, that script uses special features that are only provided by the Youtube server.

Answer (score 22):

This actually is possible with JavaScript, though browser support would be spotty.  You can use XHR2 to download the file from the server to the browser as a Blob, create a URL to the Blob, create an anchor with its href property set to that URL, set the download property to whatever you want the filename to be, and then click the link.  This works in Google Chrome, but I haven't verified support in other browsers.

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      a = document.createElement('a'), file;

xhr.open('GET', 'someFile', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function () {
    file = new Blob([xhr.response], { type : 'application/octet-stream' });
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = 'someName.gif';  // Set to whatever file name you want
    // Now just click the link you created
    // Note that you may have to append the a element to the body somewhere
    // for this to work in Firefox
    a.click();
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I can't make it work. In Chrome the file gets saved with the correct name, but it has a zero length. In Firefox, the length is correct, but the name is dsQ9lPaj.bin.part etc.

Comment: There's a fix in the works for Firefox.  Expect it Q1 this year.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with client-side JavaScript, you need to set the response header...

.NET

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=myname.txt")
```

Or PHP

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=myname.txt')
```

Also available in other server-side languages of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

The filename for downloading is set in the header ([take a look at "Content-Disposition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses)), wich is created on server-side.

There's no way you could change that with pure javascript on a file you're linking to unless you have access to the server-side (that way you could pass an additional parameter giving the filename and change the server-side behaviour to set the header to match that... but that would also be possible with pure html, no need for javascript). Conclusion: Javascript is absolute useless to achive what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can [*probably* do this with a Chrome](http://caniuse.com/filesystem) userscript, but it cannot be done (yet) with Greasemonkey (Firefox) javascript.

Workaround methods (easiest to hardest):

1. Add the links with Greasemonkey but use the excellent [*DownThemAll!* add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) to download and rename the videos.
2. Download the videos as-is and use a batch file, shell-script, Python program, etc. to rename them.
3. Use Greasemonkey's [`GM_xmlhttpRequest()`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) function to send the files to your own web application on a server you control.
   This server could be your own PC running [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (or similar).
4. Write your own Firefox add-on, instead of a Greasemonkey script.  Add-ons have the required privileges, Greasemonkey does not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Do you know how this script is able to rename the files on youtube with only javascript: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/62634

Comment: That script is using something close to method 3; using a feature that Youtube deliberately provides in its server.  Notice that the download links are all like: `<a href="... youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams= ...title=Fancy Rename"...>Low Definition MP4...</a>`.  That ***title*** parameter tells the server what filename to send back when the link is clicked.  Most sites are not so nice as to provide this service.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you will not be able to do this right from the client itself. You could first upload the file onto the server with the desired name, and then serve it back up to the end user (in which case your file name would be used).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are looking for such a solution for your nasty downloading chrome extension, you should look into chrome.downloads API, it needs additional permission ('downloads') and allows you to specify filename. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

However there is a problem I'm facing right now. The chrome extension I'm refactoring has 600k+ user base and adding a new permission would disable the extension for all of them. So it is no-go solution for me, but if you are developing a new extension you definitely should use it.