# Have a <a href="cb289e02-ed2b-4daa-">pdf</a> save with a more descriptive filename?

Tags: html

I have a document that is accessible from a url such as 
`http://www.myCompany.com/Documents/cb289e02-ed2b-4daa-8`. I am using

`<a href="http://www.myCompany.com/Documents/cb289e02-ed2b-4daa-8">TitleCodeReport</a>` 
In an email that is being sent to the users of this report.

I want to make a link so that when the user clicks it, it will save with a friendlier name like `TitleCodeReport.pdf` instead of `cb289e02-ed2b-4daa-8`.  Any idea how I would do that?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801076/renaming-files-when-downloading-it

Comment: here is another one with ASP, in case u use that instead of PHP => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526849/how-do-i-change-a-filename-on-download-with-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in HTML with the [HTML5 `download` attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute).

```
<a href="http://foo.com/files/adlafjlxjewfasd89asd8f.pdf" download="foo.pdf">Download It</a>
```